# Installing Silverlight plugin on offline PC - is it possible?

Tags: .net, silverlight, plugins, offline

Let's presume you need to show your shiny new touchscreen-optimised Silverlight application to your boss during trans-atlantic flight. How can you do that on *his* notebook if the only thing you have is CD  containing your application and (maybe) your trusty 4" pocket notebook without mouse controls (:)) but with silverlight plugin installed.

So, Is it possible to **install Silverlight plugin without internet connection** available?

When you run default silverlight plugin installer it downloads *real* installer from internet and runs it.
Is it possible to collect this "real installer" from (e.g.) Temporary Internet Files folder and run it directly or avoid download step in some other way? 
Maybe there is an alternative silverlight plugin installer for those hoping to test their application against older versions? (ilder versions of Flash player are available in this fashion).

Related question: what about *un*installing Silverlight plugin?

Answer (score 2):

This article explains how to perform an offline install of Silverlight: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/09/29/install-silverlight-2-rc0-offline.aspx

As to how to uninstall, see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/rpomeroy/archive/2008/06/10/how-to-manually-clean-up-a-bad-silverlight-installation.aspx

Comment: +1 despite the fact that I don't generally upvote the "Let me google that for you" type answers.  Since its right there at the top of the list the OP could've saved themselves the trouble of asking the question at all.

Comment: thanks for links, but they explain how to install silverlight developer environment, while I was asking about silverlight *browser plugin*